# What happens if i use a constraint on a PK?

Tags: postgresql, constraints

What happens if I have a PK and I put a constraint on it. 
I know that when I try to write in the DB the same entity, it will overwrite it instead of giving a conflict due to the constraint. 
Question is why?
It overwrites it because it is written with hibernates - spring data jpa - and method is jpaRepository.save(). So it does overwrite the entity if it has the same PK and all others columns the same.

This happens even in the following case:
I have a constraint on 3 VARCHAR columns: (name, version, type)
I have a PK formed by appending the 3 VARCHARS togather: name_version_type

this is what happens in sql file with spring and flyway when the schema is created:

```
CREATE TABLE package
(
   id surrogate_id PRIMARY KEY,
   CONSTRAINT uq_package_name_version_type UNIQUE(surrogate_id),
   name VARCHAR NOT NULL,
   version VARCHAR NOT NULL,
   type VARCHAR NOT NULL
)
;
```

this is what happens in java with Hibernate:

```
@Table(name = PackageEntity.TABLE_NAME, uniqueConstraints = {
    @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"package"}, name = ConstraintName.SURROGATE_ID)})
```

the columns:

```
@NotNull
private String name;

@NotNull
private String version;

@NotNull
private String type;

@Id
@Column(name = "surrogate_id")
private String surrogateId;
```

and how surrogate id is created:

```
public static final String hash(String name, String version, String type)
{
    return new StringBuilder().append(name)
                              .append("_").append(version)
                              .append("_").append(type)
                              .toString();
}
```

I expect that it sees the same PK and attempts to overwrite the entity but I also expect to stop the transaction because it sees the conflict on the 3 column. It doesn't happen. It only considers the PK. Why?

Comment: When you have a PK and try to insert a row with the same PK, it doesn't update it (unless you use UPSERT). It throws an error of duplicate key and doesn't look any other constraits. It doesn't make sense to look anything else if it will not be posible to insert the row

Comment: Can you please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add the `CREATE TABLE` statement including all constraints you create as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Answer (score 1):

It is allowed, but superfluous, to add a `UNIQUE` constraint on a primary key, because being a primary key implies uniqueness.

You should drop the extra constraint, because it causes an extra index to be created, which will waste space and slow down data modifications.

Comment: So considering @Roman Konoval's answer as well, it means that it makes an update but with no constraint because the constraint is ignored due to PK, right?

Comment: No, the `UNIQUE` constraint is checked during an `UPDATE`, because it is backed by a unique index. So you pay the price of two uniqueness checks (and two index modifications!), but you have no benefit, because a primary key already guarantees uniqueness.

Answer (score 1):

In spring `JpaRepository` by default the `save` operation works as following:

1. if the entity does not have a primary key (the field with `@Id` annotation) set - new record in created in the database using `INSERT` SQL statement
2. if the entity does have primary key - the existing record is modified using `UPDATE` SQL statement.

So in your case spring thinks that you are doing the update of the existing entity and no insert happens so no conflict happens. That's why the constraint is useless.

To overcome this you can implement [Persistable](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/domain/Persistable.html) interface and `isNew` method specifically to let spring know that you are inserting a new entity. In this case spring will do insert and not update.

Comment: Thank you sir! I got it now.